# .htaccess redirect image url to new location

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a very large site which has lots of images which have a url like `/dir1/dir2/images/xyz.jpg` or /dir1/images/xyz.jpg`. (any number of directories before leading up to the page).

These images have to be moved to a single images directory at the root of the site and rather than going in and altering all the urls is it possible using the .htaccess file to point them to `/images.xyz.jpg`? (with the slash at the beginning)

I already have this code at the beginning of my htaccess file for other url cleaning but can't make this image url altering work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(downloads|includes)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*?)(images)/(.+)$ /$1$2.$3 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(downloads|includes)($|/) - [L]
```

Comment: Awesome... however, your code has highlighted an error in mine. The actual url of the image is `/dir1/dir2/images/xyz.jpg`. I was forgetting that the url is relative to the page. However the number directories deep could be different. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: @Tom Just remove the starting `^`.